# Telegram BOT - how to add icon?

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

How do you add an icon to the telegram bot?

example command:

*/stats*

response code:

```
var response = '';
response += '*Pool*\n';
response += 'Hashrate: ' + poolHashrate + '\n';
response += 'Connected Miners: ' + poolMiners + '\n';
response += 'Active Workers: ' + poolWorkers + '\n';
response += 'Blocks Found: ' + poolBlocks + '\n';
response += 'Last Block: ' + poolLastBlock + '\n';
response += 'Current Effort: ' + currentEffort + '\n';
response += '\n';
response += '*Network*\n';
response += 'Hashrate: ' + networkHashrate + '\n';
response += 'Difficulty: ' + networkDiff + '\n';
response += 'Block Height: ' + networkHeight + '\n';
response += 'Block Found: ' + networkLastBlock + '\n';
response += 'Last Reward: ' + networkLastReward;
return bot.sendMessage(chatId, response, { parse_mode: 'Markdown' });
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, what do you mean by icon? Do you want to change the bot's profile icon? Explain more please.

Comment: if you're about icons for buttons (on the keyboard), you can use utf8-codes here a list of codes: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html. I agree with @Naser.Sadeghi, can you explain what do you mean on "icon"?

Answer (score 7):

1. talk to **@BotFather**
2. type */setuserpic*
3. select your bot from the list (or type its name)
4. use send media to upload the image (must be at least 150x150)